# Autoform-typeahead output limitation

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, twitter-typeahead, simple-schema

I use `comerc:autoform-typeahead` package (it works with aldeed:autoforms) in my meteor app to implement typeahead.
It's [DOCS](https://github.com/comerc/meteor-autoform-typeahead) say we can use it like this

```
{   
    tags: {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      type: "typeahead",
      afFieldInput: {
        typeaheadOptions: {},
        typeaheadDatasets: {}
      }
    }   
  } 
}
```

This package works, and it shows all matching result. The question is, how can we limit our output (to 5, for example) ?
These solutions:

```
typeaheadOptions: {limit : 5}
```

or

```
typeaheadDatasets: {limit: 5}
```

don't work.

The second question: is there any other typeahead package for autoforms with limit option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the limit inside your server side search method. My question [here](https://github.com/comerc/meteor-autoform-typeahead/issues/11) will be a useful reference for you.